# All permutations of the pairs that add to squares

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking

> Given a number, this program would find "all permutations of the pairs that add to squares" from 1 to number.
>
> E.g: Given an input number of 16, one of the possible answers would be:
>
> ```
> 8:1:15:10:6:3:13:12:4:5:11:14:2:7:9:16
> ```
>
> and its reverse.

Note that the function called `hasIntegerRoot` has been commented out for a purpose. I would appreciate if reviewer would chose me to use `hasIntegerRoot` over currently used `List<Integer> squareList`.

I'm looking for code review, best practices, optimizations etc.

Verifying Complexity (where \$n\$ is the input number):

- Time: \$O(n!)\$
- Space: \$O(n!)\$

```
public final class PairSquare {

    private PairSquare() {};

    /**
     *  Given a number, this program would find "all permutations of the pairs that add to squares" from 1 to number"
     * 
     * @param num        The number upto which adjacent numbers should sum to a sqaure 
     * @return           A List of all the lists/chains of integers such that adjacent numbers sum upto a square.
     */
    public static List<List<Integer>> pairSquare (int num) {
        if (num <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input number " + num + " should be less than equal to zero.");

        final List<List<Integer>> pairSquaresList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        final List<Integer> squareList = squareList(num);
        final LinkedHashSet<Integer> elements = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) { 
            elements.add(i);
            getSqaureLists(i, num, elements, pairSquaresList, squareList);
            elements.remove(i);
        }
        return pairSquaresList;
    }

    private static List<Integer> squareList(int num) {
        int limit = num + (num  - 1);
        int n = 2;
        final List<Integer> sqaureList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int square;
        while ((square = n * n) <= limit) {
            sqaureList.add(square);
            n++;
        }
        return sqaureList;
    }

//    private static boolean hasIntegerRoot(int x) {
//        double root = Math.sqrt(x);
//        return  root == (int)root;
//    }

    private static void getSqaureLists(int currNum, int num, LinkedHashSet<Integer> elements, List<List<Integer>> pairSquareList, List<Integer> squareList) {
        if (elements.size() == num) {
            pairSquareList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(elements));
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            // a number has already been added in the list. deduping.
            if (elements.contains(i))  continue;

//            // checking if the adjacent numbers add up to a square of an int.
//            if (hasIntegerRoot(i + currNum)) {
//                elements.add(i);
//                getSqaureLists(i, num, elements, pairSquareList, squareList);
//            }

            if (squareList.contains(i + currNum)) {
                elements.add(i);
                getSqaureLists(i, num, elements, pairSquareList, squareList);
            }

            elements.remove(i);
        }
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(8, 1, 15, 10, 6, 3, 13, 12, 4, 5, 11, 14, 2, 7, 9, 16);
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(16, 9, 7, 2, 14, 11, 5, 4, 12, 13, 3, 6, 10, 15, 1, 8);

        List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        listOfLists.add(list1);
        listOfLists.add(list2);

        Assert.assertEquals(listOfLists, pairSquare(16));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you don't seem to be concerned with the order of any of the collections of objects you use, only membership in those collections, `Set` is probably the better `Collection` to use, instead of `List`.  I imagine that `Set.contains` is going to be more efficient than `List.contains`.

Also, it's not clear to me that recursion is the way to go here.  If I were you, I would try to walk through the code with a low value for the input number and see what it's doing.  It looks like for every integer between 1 and num, you're calling `getSqaureLists` num x num times.  That seems like overkill.  Recursion typically does some work and then passes a smaller set of work to the recursive call.  You need to clarify how you split up that work.  If that's not working, a iterative solution might be clearer.

You also have some code to check for duplicates.  You shouldn't need to do that.  Whether you a doing an iterative or recursive solution, you should be able to avoid ever testing duplicate values.

Answer (score 3):

**Meaningful names** - names like `PairSqaure`, `squareList`, `pairSquareList` do not add any information about the code, and are similar enough to confuse. Other names like `i`, `num`, `elements` are even less helpful. `findPairsThatAddUpToSquares(int maxValue)` is much more valuable, and make most of the documentation redundant.

**Don't use the same name twice** - you use `squareList` as a method name as well as a variable name, this is unreadable, and potentially error prone.

**Don't overkill** - the problem is finding all pairs of numbers which correspond to some restriction - it's like writing a big table with n lines and n rows, and marking each one which fits - that would be \$O(n^2)\$, anything more complex would be wrong. Your use of recursion is unclear, and I can't see the point of it a simple loop would suffice:

```
for (int highNum = 2; highNum <= maxNum; highNum++) {
    for (int lowNum = 1; lowNum < highNuml; lowNum++) {
        if (fitsTheBill(lowNum, highNum)) {
            results.add(new int[] { lowNum, highNum });
            results.add(new int[] { highNum, lowNum });
        }
    }
}
```

**Use correct container** - using a pre-calculated table of squares is fine, but if you put it in an `ArrayList`, each `contains` will cost you \$O(n)\$. Using `Set` will do the same thing in \$O(1)\$.

**Unclear requirements** - "all permutations of the pairs that add to squares" - what I understand from this is that the result should be a list of *pairs* containing [n,m] and [m,n] for each pair that adds to a square, you sample output though is two arrays containing a list of numbers in which every `item[i]+item[i+1]` adds up to a square. This may be what you meant, but this hardly constitutes *all permutations* of such an answer - `15:10:6:3:13:12:4:5:11:14:2:7:9:16:8:1` will also qualify, but it is not part of your answer...

Here is a refactored solution with complexity of \$O(n^2)\$ in time and \$O(n)\$ in space:

```
public final class PairsThatAddUpToSquaresFinder {

    private PairsThatAddUpToSquaresFinder() {};

    public static List<List<Integer>> findPairsThatAddUpToSquares (int maxValue) {
        if (maxValue <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input number " + maxValue + " should be less than equal to zero.");

        final List<Integer> pairsThatAddUpToSquares = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        final Set<Integer> precalculatedSquares = calculateAllSquaresUpTo(maxValue);
        for (int highNum = 2; highNum <= maxValue; highNum++) {
            for (int lowNum = 1; lowNum < highNuml; lowNum++) {
                if (precalculatedSquares.contains(lowNum + highNum)) {
                    pairsThatAddUpToSquares.add(lowNum);
                    pairsThatAddUpToSquares.add(highNum);
                }
            }
        }
        final List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        result.add(pairsThatAddUpToSquares);
        result.add(Collections.reverse(pairsThatAddUpToSquares.clone()));
        return result;
    }

    private static List<Integer> calculateAllSquaresUpTo(int maxValue) {
        int limit = maxValue + (maxValue  - 1);
        int n = 2;
        final List<Integer> sqaureList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int square;
        while ((square = n * n) <= limit) {
            sqaureList.add(square);
            n++;
        }
        return sqaureList;
    }
}
```